# mergeSort going into an infinite loop?

Tags: java, arraylist, mergesort

As a part of a project I'm working on, we need to take a "Song" Object, a list of which are in the ArrayList "songCollection". I need to merge sort the file based on title, rank, artist, or year, but when executed, the code goes into an infinite loop (StackOverflow Error) and I'm not sure why. What's wrong with my code:
A list of songs:
1965    55  Gary Lewis and the Playboys Everybody Loves A Clown 
1963    526 Ben E. King How Can I Forget 
1979    207 Ashford and Simpson Found A Cure 1981   96  Andy Gibb   Time Is Time 1996   169 Total   When Boy Meets Girl
1962    384 Linda Scott Yesiree 
1957    315 Frank Sinatra   Your Love For Me 
1978    302 John Denver I Want To Live 
1954    304 Stan Kenton & His Orchestra The Creep 
1993    199 Exposï¿½    As Long As I Can Dream 
1989    269 House Of Lords  I Wanna Be Loved 
1950    267 Benny Goodman Sextet    Oh, Babe! 
1948    295 Tex Williams & The Western Caravan  Suspicion

Code:
//to change a line above into a song, add it to songCollection

```
 ArrayList<Song> songCollection = new ArrayList<Song>();
 public SongCollection(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
      while (input.hasNextLine())
      {
         addSong(input.nextLine());

      }
}
//getter method
public ArrayList<Song> getSongCollection() {
    return songCollection;
}
public void addSong(String line) {
    //parse the line read from the song file, create the song, and add it to the collection
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line, "\t");
    String year = token.nextToken();
    int intYear = Integer.parseInt(year);

    String rank = token.nextToken();
    int intRank = Integer.parseInt(rank);

    String artist = token.nextToken();
    String name = token.nextToken();

    Song song = new Song(intYear, intRank, artist, name);
    songCollection.add(song);




}


                 public ArrayList<Song>  mergeSort(ArrayList<Song> all, String filter, String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
     //overarching method, divides the array list into left and right array lists, then divides and sorts, and then finally merges back
     //distinction: use of mergeString vs mergeInt based on the type of filter that the list is being sorted for. 
     ArrayList<Song> left = new ArrayList<Song>();
        ArrayList<Song> right = new ArrayList<Song>();
        int center;

        if (all.size() == 1) {    
            return all;
        } 
        else {
            center = all.size()/2;
            for (int i=center; i<all.size(); i++) {
                    right.add(all.get(i));
            }


            //left  = mergeSort(left,filter, file);
            //right = mergeSort(right, filter, file);

            // Merge the results back together.
            if (filter.equalsIgnoreCase("year") || filter.equalsIgnoreCase("rank"))
                mergeInt(left, right, all, filter);
            if (filter.equalsIgnoreCase("artist") || filter.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                mergeString(left,right,all,filter);

        }
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new File(file));
        for (int x = 0; x < songCollection.size(); x++) {
            out.println(all.get(x).toString());
        }
        out.close();
        return all;

    }
            private void mergeString(ArrayList<Song> left, ArrayList<Song> right, ArrayList<Song> whole, String filter) {
        //'mergeX' for the string filters
        int leftIndex = 0;
        int rightIndex = 0;
        int wholeIndex = 0;

        //checks whether filter is artist or type 
        if(filter.equalsIgnoreCase("artist")) {
            while (leftIndex < left.size() && rightIndex < right.size()) {
                if ( (left.get(leftIndex).artist.compareTo(right.get(rightIndex).artist)) < 0) {
                    whole.set(wholeIndex, left.get(leftIndex));
                    leftIndex++;
                } else {
                    whole.set(wholeIndex, right.get(rightIndex));
                    rightIndex++;
                }
                wholeIndex++;
            }

            ArrayList<Song> rest;
            int restIndex;
            if (leftIndex >= left.size()) {
                // The left ArrayList has been use up...
                rest = right;
                restIndex = rightIndex;
            } else {
                rest = left;
                restIndex = leftIndex;
            }

            for (int i=restIndex; i<rest.size(); i++) {
                whole.set(wholeIndex, rest.get(i));
                wholeIndex++;
            }
        }
        if(filter.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
            while (leftIndex < left.size() && rightIndex < right.size()) {
                if ( (left.get(leftIndex).title.compareTo(right.get(rightIndex).title)) < 0) {
                    whole.set(wholeIndex, left.get(leftIndex));
                    leftIndex++;
                } else {
                    whole.set(wholeIndex, right.get(rightIndex));
                    rightIndex++;
                }
                wholeIndex++;
            }

            ArrayList<Song> rest;
            int restIndex;
            if (leftIndex >= left.size()) {
                rest = right;
                restIndex = rightIndex;
            } else {
                rest = left;
                restIndex = leftIndex;
            }

            for (int i=restIndex; i<rest.size(); i++) {
                whole.set(wholeIndex, rest.get(i));
                wholeIndex++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void mergeInt(ArrayList<Song> left, ArrayList<Song> right, ArrayList<Song> whole, String filter) {
        //same as mergeString, but for int fields
        int leftIndex = 0;
        int rightIndex = 0;
        int wholeIndex = 0;

        if(filter.equalsIgnoreCase("year")) {
            while (leftIndex < left.size() && rightIndex < right.size()) {
                if  (left.get(leftIndex).year < right.get(rightIndex).year) {
                    whole.set(wholeIndex, left.get(leftIndex));
                    leftIndex++;
                } else {
                    whole.set(wholeIndex, right.get(rightIndex));
                    rightIndex++;
                }
                wholeIndex++;
            }

            ArrayList<Song> rest;
            int restIndex;
            if (leftIndex >= left.size()) {
                rest = right;
                restIndex = rightIndex;
            } else {
                rest = left;
                restIndex = leftIndex;
            }

            for (int i=restIndex; i<rest.size(); i++) {
                whole.set(wholeIndex, rest.get(i));
                wholeIndex++;
            }
        }
        if(filter.equalsIgnoreCase("rank")) {
            while (leftIndex < left.size() && rightIndex < right.size()) {
                if  (left.get(leftIndex).rank < (right.get(rightIndex).rank)) {
                    whole.set(wholeIndex, left.get(leftIndex));
                    leftIndex++;
                } else {
                    whole.set(wholeIndex, right.get(rightIndex));
                    rightIndex++;
                }
                wholeIndex++;
            }

            ArrayList<Song> rest;
            int restIndex;
            if (leftIndex >= left.size()) {
                rest = right;
                restIndex = rightIndex;
            } else {
                rest = left;
                restIndex = leftIndex;
            }
            for (int i=restIndex; i<rest.size(); i++) {
                whole.set(wholeIndex, rest.get(i));
                wholeIndex++;
            }
```

Comment: This sounds like an excellent opportunity to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: can you post up error messages that you get?

Comment: My error message is: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at Song.SongCollection.mergeSort(SongCollection.java:270)", and line 270 is  left  = mergeSort(left,filter, file);

Comment: Could you add a compilable example? so we can test?

Comment: Use java's collections to sort this... no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Edit your question please, don't post comment to append information.

Comment: I've added a sample list of songs (not converted), as well as how to convert them to songs

Comment: I don't find the line where the StackOverflowError occurs in the code that you've posted

Comment: It's under the mergeSort method

Comment: Your code doesn't put any songs into the `left` list. It then tries to sort this empty list, which it happily splits into empty left and right sublists and then again tries to sort the left list - until a StackOverflow occurs.